# Could you pleas help me in the following stanford-nlp OpenIE

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I run the same demo example on the website with the following sentence:
"Hudson was born in Hampstead, which is a suburb of London."

and give me the following,

Hudson  be      bear

and I was expecting the following relations:

(Hudson, was born in, Hampstead)

(Hampstead, is a suburb of, London)

> 

```js
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.util.RelationTriple;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.NaturalLogicAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Properties;

/** A demo illustrating how to call the OpenIE system programmatically.
 */
public class OpenIEDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Create the Stanford CoreNLP pipeline
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse,natlog,openie");
    //tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse,natlog,openie
    //tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,regexner,parse,mention,entitymentions,coref,kbp
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    // Annotate an example document.
    Annotation doc = new Annotation(args[0]);
    pipeline.annotate(doc);
   // Loop over sentences in the document
    for (CoreMap sentence : doc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      // Get the OpenIE triples for the sentence
      Collection<RelationTriple> triples =
           sentence.get(NaturalLogicAnnotations.RelationTriplesAnnotation.class);
      // Print the triples
      for (RelationTriple triple : triples) {
        System.out.println(triple.confidence + "\t" +
            triple.subjectLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
            triple.relationLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
            triple.objectLemmaGloss());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the system is not wrong, though certainly undergenerating possible relations. `Hudson be bear` is just asserting that Hudson was born (a true fact). This in particular was caused by the ref edge from Hampstead -ref-> which. This should be fixed in subsequent versions of the code.

In general though, like all NLP systems, OpenIE has a certain accuracy rate that's under 100%, and you should never expect the system to produce completely correct output. Especially for a task like Open IE, where even getting agreement on what "correct" means is difficult.

Comment: Thank you for your time, you mean that the code is working in a later version? I have one question in openIE could I be able to define my relation that I want the OpenIE to detect?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Semgrex](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/semgrex/SemgrexPattern.html), which'll let you define custom patterns over dependency trees. [the demo site](http://corenlp.run) has a debugger on the bottom where you can test out patterns.